# Angular 2 EventEmitter Issue

Tags: angular

I have an `@Output` of type `EventEmitter<any>` in a component. The output works if I call `.emit()` on it in a function after a button click. I am able to catch the event in the parent component in that case without issue. However, that is really just as a test measure. When I try to do what I actually want to do, which is make a database call, and then emit an event on success, the event is never emitted from the child component or caught in the parent component. Here's a little bit of code to show what I mean:

```
testOutput() {
    this.outputEvent.emit({event: 'buttonClick', message: 'Here is some output'});
}

makeAnUpdate(form) {
    this._service.makeDbCall(data).subscribe(result => {
        this.variable = result;
        this.outputEvent.emit({ message: 'Here is a message to pass', success: true });
    });
}
```

I also tried to call the function that just emits the event from inside the subscribe part of the below function, and it still didn't work:

```
makeAnUpdate(form) {
    this._service.makeDbCall(data).subscribe(result => {
        this.variable = result;
        this.testOutput();
    });
}
```

Has anyone else had this issue? Again, the `testOutput` function above works if you call it and only it, but not from inside the `makeAnUpdate` function.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing what `this._service.makeDbCall(data)` does. I assume the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` doesn't get called.

Comment: It does get called. The call is made to the database, and comes back into that function. I know for sure because if I do a `console.log` right before the event emitter inside there, the `console.log` works and shows up.

Comment: The I assume the execution somehow leaves Angulars zone. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The callback of the observable returned from `makeDbCall` might run outside Angulars zone. Please try

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}
  makeAnUpdate(form) {
    this._service.makeDbCall(data).subscribe(result => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.variable = result;
          this.outputEvent.emit({ message: 'Here is a message to pass', success: true });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This has the same effect as without the `ngZone.run`. A `console.log` prints out, data comes back from the database, etc. but the event is not emitted.

Comment: Hard to tell. There isn't much that can go wrong. I guess we need a more complete example that shows how the component that listens to the event and that emits the event are related, where methods and event handlers are and how they are called.

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/c3f6633008093eb268fd5b2f618c0934) with example files that are set up just like the real ones. This is really straightforward; I don't really know what other information I could possibly provide.

Comment: It's unlikely this example works in any way. `@Output` should be `@Output()`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `()`, but they are actually in the code.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. I'm quite sure there is nothing wrong with the code you provided and the issue is caused by something else. How does the service look like?

Comment: The service is a simple `HTTP` call that maps the response to `json`... Very vanilla stuff.

Comment: I can't imagine this not to work then. Maybe you can try on a different machine or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

I have the similar issue, EventEmitter.subscribe only runs in the class it is defined.